# Don't work AutoMapper IncludeMembers for Nested Child

Tags: c#, automapper

When I run following code I get an error: 
*Property 'NestedInnerSource NestedInnerSource' is not defined for type 'MapperTest.Program+Source' (Parameter 'property')*

```
class Program
    {
        class Source
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public InnerSource InnerSource { get; set; }
            public OtherInnerSource OtherInnerSource { get; set; }
        }
        class InnerSource
        {
            public NestedInnerSource NestedInnerSource { get; set; }
        }
        class OtherInnerSource
        {
            public NestedOtherInnerSource NestedOtherInnerSource { get; set; }
        }
        class NestedInnerSource
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }
        class NestedOtherInnerSource
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
        }
        class Destination
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var source = new Source
            {
                Name = "name",
                InnerSource = new InnerSource { NestedInnerSource = new NestedInnerSource { Description = "description" } },
                OtherInnerSource = new OtherInnerSource { NestedOtherInnerSource = new NestedOtherInnerSource { Title = "title" } }
            };

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().IncludeMembers(s => s.InnerSource.NestedInnerSource, s => s.OtherInnerSource.NestedOtherInnerSource);
                cfg.CreateMap<NestedInnerSource, Destination>(MemberList.None);
                cfg.CreateMap<NestedOtherInnerSource, Destination>(MemberList.None);
            });

            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            var destination = mapper.Map<Destination>(source);
        }
    }
```

This code I get from https://github.com/lbargaoanu/AutoMapper/blob/1b27cefc70289159f1f8be229611847e0b8b3051/src/UnitTests/IMappingExpression/IncludeMembers.cs
When I run this unit test everything is ok, but in my Console application I catch the error.

Maybe somebody know what is the problem?

Comment: Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.